# Centrar Imagen css

Tags: css

Me gustaría saber como puedo insertar una imagen debajo de mi formulario de login. He intentado hacerlo mediante css con el div imgPubli que podeis ver un poco mas abajo en la pagina html y en el css tambien.  El problema que tengo es que la imagen no se queda centrada debajo del form. La parte izquierda de la imagen imgPubli si esta alineada con el form pero al terner un width mayor, se sale por la derecha.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 }


.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active, a.ui-button:active, .ui-button:active, .ui-button.ui-state-active:hover { /*Boton aceptar*/
    border: 0px solid #333333;
    background: #777777;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/*-----------------------------------------*/

.Absolute-Center {
  
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 }

.text { 
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

/*Se refiere a los addon de login y registro*/
.input-group-addon {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #686A10;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}



.Absolute-Center.is-Responsive {
  width: 50%; 
 
  min-width: 360px;
  max-width: 800px; 
  padding: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 400px) {
 #logo{
   margin: auto;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   background-image:url("../img/cana.jpg");
 
 }
 
 

}

#logo-error{
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width:90px;
  height:75px;
  background-image:url("../img/error.png");
 }
 
#contenedor{
  padding: 0px 70px 0px 70px;
 
 }

 
#txtInfo{
 text-align: justify;
}

/*Estos son los labels de volver a login y la interrogación*/
#idLogin,#lblInfo{
 text-align: center;
}


 
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { /*No quiero que me haga el sombreado en vista movil*/
 #contenedor{
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
   box-shadow: none;
  /* border-bottom:none;*/
  border-right: none;
 }
 
 /*Adapto el texto a vista movil*/
 #textoRegistro{ /* Este div de muestra el texto de aviso de registro web*/
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width:320px;
  height:160px;
  font-weight: 900;       
   font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  color:#337AB7;
  font-size:1em;
  
 }
}

#chkConsentimiento{
padding-bottom: 10px;
}


.btn-primary {
 background: transparent;
 border-color: #686A10;
 color:#686A10;
 
}

.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active
{
  background-color:transparent;
  border-color:#686A10;
   outline: none !important;
 
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(142,145,0,0.71) inset, 0 0 1px rgba(142,145,0,0.71);
}

.btn-primary:active:hover
{
   color: #686A10;
   background-color: transparent;
   border-color:#686A10;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(142,145,0,0.71) inset, 0 0 1px rgba(142,145,0,0.71);
}


.btn-primary:hover
{
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #686A10;
  color: #686A10;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(142,145,0,0.71) inset, 0 0 1px rgba(142,145,0,0.71);
}

.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary:active {
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: none;
   color:#686A10;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(142,145,0,0.71) inset, 0 0 1px rgba(142,145,0,0.71);
}

.form-control {
   border: 1px solid #686A10;
}


input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,

.uneditable-input:focus {   
  border-color: rgba(142,145,0,0.71);
  box-shadow: 0 0.8px 0.8px rgba(142,145,0,0.71) inset, 0 0 0.8px rgba(142,145,0,0.71);
}


footer {  /*Fondo de pie de pagina vista  normal */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105px;
  }
  
  
 h5.acceso{
 font-weight: 900;       
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color: #686A10;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 } 
 
 a { /*Cambia de color el enlace*/
    color: #686A10;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleLogin.css"><!--Mi Estilo-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title></title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/css/keyboard.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleLogin.css"><!--Mi Estilo-->

</head>

<body>
 <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive  ">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
   <div id="contenedor"> 
    <a href="http://www.google.es">
     <div id="logo"></div>
    </a>
    <div id="logo-error" style="display:none"></div>
    <form  method="post" action="javascript:login();" name="loginForm"  id="loginForm">
     <center><H5 CLASS="acceso "><div class="col-md-12" id="lblRegistro">- SOLICITAR CODIGO DE ACCESO -</div></h5></center>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idUsuario"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  title="N&uacute;meros y letra may&uacute;scula y sin espacios"  name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Introduzca DNI o CIF" required />          
     </div>
     <div id="idTextoError" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
      <input  type="password"  class="form-control"  title="Introduzca  clave." name='txtClave' id="idClave" placeholder="Clave" required />     
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-sm   btn btn-primary btn-block"><strong>Aceptar</strong></button>
     </div>
     
    </form>  
    
   </div>  
   
  <a href="https://www.google.es/"><img src="img/imgPubli.jpg" width="100%"></a>
   
  </div>
   
 </div>
  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: deberiás agregar algunas imágenes con rutas existentes en tu snippet

Comment: Gracias, la verdad es que no se como

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se entiende muy bien si quieres solo una imagen o una imagen con un link. En cualquier caso puedes usar el elemento de `HTML` **[img](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)**.
Esa img la coloque fuera del div contenedor, y le di formato con css.
El problema es que el contenedor que tiene arruba, el `Absolute-Center` tiene `position:absolute` y se pone delante de la img. Para este caso sobrescribi el estilo del css con:

```
.Absolute-Center{
  position: relative !important; 
}
```

El elemento `img` queda de la siguiente manera:

```
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="img" id="imgFooter">
```

Y su css queda asi:

```
#imgFooter{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active, a.ui-button:active, .ui-button:active, .ui-button.ui-state-active:hover {
  /*Boton aceptar*/
  border: 0px solid #333333;
  background: #777777;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/*-----------------------------------------*/
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.text {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/*Se refiere a los addon de login y registro*/
.input-group-addon {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #686A10;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.Absolute-Center.is-Responsive {
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 360px;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 400px) {
  #logo {
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("../img/cana.jpg");
  }

  #imgPubli {
    width: 541px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("../img/imgPubli.jpg");
  }
}

#logo-error {
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 75px;
  background-image: url("../img/error.png");
}

#contenedor {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#txtInfo {
  text-align: justify;
}

/*Estos son los labels de volver a login y la interrogación*/
#idLogin, #lblInfo {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  /*No quiero que me haga el sombreado en vista movil*/
  #contenedor {
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
    /* border-bottom:none;*/
    border-right: none;
  }

  /*Adapto el texto a vista movil*/
  #textoRegistro {
    /* Este div de muestra el texto de aviso de registro web*/
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 160px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #337AB7;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}

#chkConsentimiento {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn-primary {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: #686A10;
  color: #686A10;
}

.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #686A10;
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71) inset, 0 0 1px rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71);
}

.btn-primary:active:hover {
  color: #686A10;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #686A10;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71) inset, 0 0 1px rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71);
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #686A10;
  color: #686A10;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71) inset, 0 0 1px rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71);
}

.btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #686A10;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71) inset, 0 0 1px rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71);
}

.form-control {
  border: 1px solid #686A10;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
.uneditable-input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71);
  box-shadow: 0 0.8px 0.8px rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71) inset, 0 0 0.8px rgba(142, 145, 0, 0.71);
}

footer {
  /*Fondo de pie de pagina vista normal */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105px;
}

h5.acceso {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #686A10;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  /*Cambia de color el enlace*/
  color: #686A10;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#imgFooter{
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.Absolute-Center{
  position: relative !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleLogin.css">
<!--Mi Estilo-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <title>Login- Grupo La Caña</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/css/keyboard.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleLogin.css">
 <!--Mi Estilo-->
</head>
<body>
 <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive  ">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
   <div id="contenedor">
    <a href="http://www.google.es">
     <div id="logo"></div>
    </a>
    <div id="logo-error" style="display:none"></div>
    <form method="post" action="javascript:login();" name="loginForm" id="loginForm">
     <center>
      <H5 CLASS="acceso ">
       <div class="col-md-12" id="lblRegistro">- SOLICITAR CODIGO DE ACCESO -</div>
      </h5>
     </center>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idUsuario" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="N&uacute;meros y letra may&uacute;scula y sin espacios" name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Introduzca DNI o CIF" required />
     </div>
     <div id="idTextoError" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" title="Introduzca  clave." name='txtClave' id="idClave" placeholder="Clave" required />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-sm   btn btn-primary btn-block"><strong>Aceptar</strong></button>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
   <a href="https:/www.google.es/">
    <div id="imgPubli"></div>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x400/000/fff" alt="img" id="imgFooter">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por el interes, lo que necesito es que la imagen de abajo, la que tu has puesto con las mededias, sea mas ancha. Si a esa imagen le pongo el ancho del formulario, la imagen no se queda bien

Comment: Entiendo, y cuan ancho quieres? que ocupe toda la pagina?

Comment: El ancho de la imagen es de 800 px

Comment: @LorenzoMartín Ahi  edite mi respuesta, calculo que es lo que pides

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intendar modificando tu div con la etiqueta

```html
<a href="http://www.grupolacana.com">
  <img src="img/css.jpg" width="100%">
</a>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: AL ponerlo, la imagen se queda totalmente centrada pero se corta por la derecha.  DIgamos que faltaria imagen hacia la derecha.

Comment: Ok, intenta cambiando tus **divs** <div id="logo"></div>  por **<img src="imagen.jpg" width="100%">

Comment: Con el div logo en principio no tengo problema, es una imagen con un ancho muy pequeño y entra bien dentro del marco. Mi problema  viene con el div  y la imagen imgPubli que es rectangular y no cable en ese marco. Voy a intentar lo que me dices

Comment: por favor lee [answer], responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Efectivamente, la imagen ahora sale toda entera, no se corta pero necesito que sea mas ancha.

Comment: Entonces ya la imagen sale bien? cual imagen quieres mas ancha o las 2? Edita tu pregunta para saber si hay avance o no y ver que mas necesitas

Comment: Creo que el problema puede estar en el css en absolute center is responsive que esta a max-width 500px. SI lo pongo a max-width: 800px la imagen se muestra correctamente, el problema es que el formulario tambien se ensancha, pero este lo puedo manejar con el padding izquierdo y derecho con el div contenedor. haciendo eso se muestra como quiero